# Windows 10 display shows 2 and 3

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 display shows 2 and 3 monitors. There's only 2 monitors.

I've tried shutting down and starting up with only the hdmi connected and it says display 2.

Comment: Laptop / desktop? Make? Model?

Comment: what's listed in `Device Manager > Display Adapters` ?